# Insert data in a case statement in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, case, apache-hive

Is it possible to insert a new row of data in a case statement in Hive.

I have a basic 'team' table, with the following fields (team_id,fname,lname).

This is what I am trying to run,

```
SELECT team_id,fname,lname,
CASE WHEN team_id = 2 THEN insert into team values (20, 'billy', 'bob'); ELSE "" END team_id
FROM team order by team_id;
```

**Error** `ParseException line 2:29 Failed to recognize predicate 'insert'. Failed rule: 'identifier' in table or column identifier`

If anyone could provide and info or solution, it would be great 

 Frostie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik we can't put any `ddl` or `dml` operation in `case` statement in hive. But workaround can be applied to solve above problem, if really needs to be solved.

```
insert into table team select 20, 'billy', 'bob' from team where team_id = 2;
```

Explanation:- it will insert a new record in **team** table if team_id=2 else nothing to insert.

Comment: @syadev Is there any way where we can update(or dml operations)  the hive table with out using orc table and hbase